# What does the long underscore in United States case citations stand for?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms

United States court cases are commonly cited like this:

> *Obergefell v. Hodges*, 576 U.S. ___ (2015)

So... what is "___" here?

Answer (score 14):

Underscores are often used to indicate that the particular case has not yet been assigned to a specific **volume** (preceding the reporter abbreviation) or **page** (following the reporter abbreviation).

In your example, the case will appear in volume 576, but the exact page has not yet been determined.

Answer (score 5):

This is a citation of a slip opinion, an opinion that has not yet been bound into a volume.  A permanent reference is not yet possible, so the blank lines serve as placeholders for the information that will be added when it becomes available.

For this reason, the page number of the slip opinion is provided, when it is required, in parentheses after the placeholder citation.  For example:

> See *United States v. 
>   Windsor,* 570 U. S. **_, _** (2013) (ALITO, J., dissenting)
>   (slip op., at 7).